# bPoll failed; You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Tags: mysql, lua, mariadb

I have got this error. Help please. (LUA)
This is the error: bPoll failed; You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY dbID DESC LIMIT 1' at line 1
and the code:

```
function addItem(sourceElement, itemId, amount, slotId, data1, data2, data3)
    if isElement(sourceElement) and itemId and amount then
        itemId = tonumber(itemId)
        amount = tonumber(amount)

        if not itemsTable[sourceElement] then
            itemsTable[sourceElement] = {}
        end

        if not slotId then
            slotId = findEmptySlot(sourceElement, itemId)
        elseif tonumber(slotId) then
            if itemsTable[sourceElement][slotId] then
                slotId = findEmptySlot(sourceElement, itemId)
            end
        end

        if slotId then
            local ownerType = getElementType(sourceElement)
            local ownerId = getElementDatabaseId(sourceElement)

            if tonumber(ownerId) then
                itemsTable[sourceElement][slotId] = {}
                itemsTable[sourceElement][slotId].locked = true

                dbQuery(
                    function (qh, sourceElement)
                        if isElement(sourceElement) then
                            local result = dbPoll(qh, 0, true)[2][1][1]

                            if result then
                                addItemEx(sourceElement, result.dbID, result.slot, result.itemId, result.amount, result.data1, result.data2, result.data3)

                                triggerItemEvent(sourceElement, "addItem", getElementType(sourceElement), result)
                            end
                        end
                    end, {sourceElement}, connection, "INSERT INTO items (itemId, slot, amount, data1, data2, data3, ownerType, ownerId) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?); SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY dbID DESC LIMIT 1", itemId, slotId, amount, data1, data2, data3, ownerType, ownerId
                )

                return true
            else
                return false
            end
        else
            return false
        end
    else
        return false
    end
end
addEvent("addItem", true)
addEventHandler("addItem", getRootElement(), addItem)
```

Comment: You have two queries there. I guess that's not allowed in this context

Comment: And...  It is not safe to grab the row you just inserted if you are depending on `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  Instead, use `last_inserted_id()` to get that id.  (That function may be spelled differently in lua.)